# Find axis-aligned rectangle with maximum area in a point set in the Euclidean plane

Tags: algorithms

On the plane $n$ points $(x_i, y_i)$ are marked. Select 4 points so that they define a rectangle with the greatest area and sides parallel to the axes.

Time limit for python is 10 seconds, for other programming languages - 2 seconds.

Input data:

- in first string integer $n$, $(4 \leq n \leq 3000)$
- in next $n$ strings pairs of integer coordinates $x_i\  y_i$ $(-10\ 000  \leq x_i,\ y_i  \leq 10\ 000)$

Output data:

- 4 different indices (numbers from $1$ to $n$), specifying the vertices of the rectangle.

I made in python, but even with tests of $n \leq 111$ it have TL.

```
n = int(input())
l = []
for i in range(n):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    l.append((a, b))

ans = [1, 2, 3, 4]
mS = 0

for i in range(0, n - 3):
    for j in range(i, n - 2):
        for k in range(j, n - 1):
            for t in range(k, n):
                r = [l[i], l[j], l[k], l[t]]
                w = sorted(r, key=lambda element:(element[0], element[1]))
                if w[0][0] == w[1][0] and w[1][1] == w[3][1] and w[3][0] == w[2][0] and w[2][1] == w[0][1]:
                    s = (w[1][1] - w[0][1]) * (w[3][0] - w[1][0])
                    if s > mS:
                        mS = s
                        ans = [i + 1, j + 1, k + 1, t + 1]

ans = sorted(ans)
print(ans[0], ans[1], ans[2], ans[3])
```

Comment: Can you put the reference to the original problem and explain properly how 4 points should define the rectangle. Do they have to be the 4 corners ? If you can also replace your python code with pseudo-code or just explain your method (even if it is simple brute-force), it would be perfect.

Comment: @Vince I can't put the link, the competition is closed. Right, my code just simple brute-force. It takes each 4 points and check does it rectangle with sides parallel to axes. This task does not go out of my head. I think there is some kind of algorithm to reduce the complexity of calculations. And points should be the 4 corners, yes.

Comment: Okay without a link you can tell which competition it is so people can check it is actually closed.

Comment: @Vince https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/12350/enter/?lang=en

Comment: I don't see any question, here. Note also that questions about coding are off-topic, here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1.** Sort all the points according to their $x$-coordinate - you will get an array of buckets, where each bucket contains a (sorted) list of points with the same $x$-coordinate. You can drop (or ignore in all subsequent steps) all the buckets, containing only single point.

**Step 2.** Define a mapping $M$, where the key will be a **closed integer interval** and the value - **ordered set of integers**. Scan all the buckets, created in the Step 1. For each bucket insert all the possible pairs of its $y$-coordinates into the mapping $M$ - *their corresponding $x$-coordinates must be inserted into the set*, corresponding to this interval:

```
function Insert(M, x, y0, y1)
  if mapping M contains element ([y0, y1] -> S)
    insert x into set S
  else
    insert element ([y0, y1] -> (x)) into mapping M
```

You can drop (or ignore in all subsequent steps) all the elements of the mapping $M$, for which their value set contains only a single number.

**Step 3.** The mapping M will contain elements like this:

$$([y_0, y_1] \rightarrow (x_0, x_1, ..., x_{m-1}))$$

The *biggest* rectangle with "vertical" side $[y_0, y_1]$ will have "horizontal" side $[x_0, x_{m-1}]$, so you can ignore all the *middle* elements of the ordered set. Finally, scan all the elements in the $M$ to find the element with largest rectangle area $A$:

$$A = (y_1 - y_0) \cdot (x_{m-1} - x_0) $$

Number of intervals in $M$ is $O(n^2)$, so time to insert into the mapping will be $O(n^2log(n))$.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the points indexes on increasing $x_i$ (time complexity $O(N\log N)$).
Then, with one loop on this sorted list, you can create the following structure:

- $GX$, list of sublists where points in the same sublist share the same $x$ value.
- $AX$, array of size $n$ giving for any $i$ the index of the sublist that contains $i$ in $GX$.

Once it is done, sort every sublist of $GX$ on increasing $y$

Let's do the same for $y$, to obtain $GY$ and $AY$. So far time complexity is still $O(N\log N)$.

A valid rectangle of four points $a, b, c, d$ starting up left clockwise should have:

- $AX[a] = AX[d]$
- $AX[b] = AX[c]$
- $AY[a] = AY[c]$
- $AY[b] = AX[d]$

Now, let's do the nested loops using $GX$ and $GY$ to hardly reduce the number of rectangles to check:

- Loop on all possible $a$
- Loop on all $b$ in $GY[AY[a]]$
- create two pointers $c$ and $d$ in respectively $GX[AX[b]]$ and $GX[AX[a]]$
- evaluate in linear time all possible $c, d$ such that $y[c] = y[d]$ (it is possible as the GX are sorted by $y$)

Complexity should be $O(N^2)$, I am not sure about that.

As all the sublists are sorted, you can also know the maximum array reachable from the upper left corner in $O(1)$. So check the potentially large rectangles first and use a stop criterion.

You finally have a $O(N^2)$ complexity instead of your $O(N^4)$.

Comment: Two possible enhancements: First, eliminate all points with a unique x-coordinate or a unique y-coordinate, which then might lead to the elimination of more points. Second, iterate in an order that tends to find large areas first: In the first two loops, a and b must be in the same list with k elements. Iterate over a and b that are k-1 apart, then k-2 apart etc., this will tend to have a long side first. If you found a solution already, you may be able to proof that you can't find a rectangle with the side (a, b) and a larger area. Otherwise, ...

Comment: ... when you iterate through the points c, d, you start with the points furthest away from a and b, and stop iterating once you know that the area of (a, b, c, d) cannot break the record so far.

Comment: @gnasher729 absolutely, that is what I meant when I said check the largest rectangles first. I did not want to give all these precisions as it does not change time complexity and would make a lot harder my answer to understand.